# getting the date from this java string, not always the same

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the date from the below string in java, I am able to write regex to get this particular instance by getting what is between the Sent: and To: with this:

```
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("Sent:(.*?)To:").matcher(emailText);
```

The issue though is that sometimes it can  be between From: and Date: or Sent: and Subject:

So, I tried to pipe (OR) in the regex like this:

```
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("Sent:(.*?)To: | From:(.*?)To: | Sent:(.*?)Subject:).matcher(emailText);
```

but it is not working.  Below is the sample of what I am working with.

*END GOAL*, is to just have a date i can send to the database in October 19, 2017 4:44 PM format.

*SAMPLE OUTPUT:*
Another test   From: John Doe [mailto:johndoe@gmail.com] Sent: Thursday, October 19, 2017 4:44 PM To: Joe Schmo Subject: This is a test!   BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP!

*SAMPLE OUTPUT2:*

this is another email ---------- Forwarded message ---------- From: Tomislav S. Jackson Date: Fri, Oct 20, 2017 at 2:32 PM Subject: To: Jonny Nobody

*SAMPLE OUTPUT3:*

Forwarding email test. Regards, Jane Doe Begin forwarded message: From: Bill Hickock Date: October 23, 2017 at 9:40:56 AM CDT To: Subject:This is a test TEST, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try to match the date only, independent on where you find it?

Comment: Oh sorry I should have mentioned, the date format is different each time as well, sometimes the October is just Oct, sometimes there is a Day before the month...I guess the point is that the date format can always be different, there is no way to tell since this is coming as a forwarded email from many different customers.

Comment: Please provide a couple more examples, e.g. what does the text look like if there is no "Sent"?

Comment: updated with 2 more examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very liberal regex you could start with, and would grab the date in your example regardless of where it is:

`(Mon|Tue|Tues|Wed|Wednes|Thu|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Satur|Sun)(day)?, \w+ \d+, 20\d\d(\sat)? \d?\d:\d\d (AM|PM)?`

No need to check if it's in the Sent, From, or any other field. You can insert more capture groups/alternations where needed to account for different formats that you might encounter. You may want to replace the word/digit tokens to be more specific if your requirements call for it. Remember to escape the back slashes when you're using this in Java.

---

Small update based on your additional examples. However, the more formats you have to look out for, the more complex a regex-based answer to your question is going to become. What I have here is already getting to be pretty hairy, and if different parts can be in a different order, you're better off abandoning regex and finding a different solution, like parsing the date and putting it in the format you want programmatically.

Comment: Perfect, this works, thank you.  You are correct, I will have to determine how many formats I will deal with, if I can even get an idea, otherwise, I will follow the suggestion of @Michael Gantman below.

Comment: If this answer was helpful and solved your problem, please select it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark beneath the vote arrows!

Comment: Actually I take that back, it is not working for the case that doesn't lead with a day, sample output 3 from above, I am working to try and fix and determine why...

Comment: Updated your code, it was not catching the seconds in sample three, also, modified to not worry about the day before the month.

`(January|February|March|April|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)? \w+ \d+, 20\d\d(\sat)? \d?\d:\d\d(:\d\d)? (AM|PM)?`

Comment: I would recommed using https://regexr.com/ or similar to test regex on sample data. I like regexr because the cheat sheet and references are right there in the same page.